# In PHP, how do I find the value associated with a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have two arrays. One contains `id=>count` and the other contains `id=>name`. I'm trying to produce a single array that is `name=>count`. Any suggestions on a straightforward way to do this?

I have looked at the [Array Functions in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and didn't see anything that stood out as doing what I want, so I'm guessing I'll need a combination of functions, but I'm having trouble coming up with something that's not convoluted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
foreach($countA as $id => $count)
{
    $newArray[$nameA[$id]] = $count;
}
```

This does assume that the keys are in correspondence between the two arrays, since your requirements are ambiguous otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_combine](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)...

```
$countArray = array(0 => 1, 1 => 5);
$namesArray = array(0 => "Bob", 1 => "Alice");

$assocArray = array_combine($namesArray, $countArray);
```

**Edit:** Here is a revised solution for the new requirements expressed in comment #2

```
$assocArray = array();
foreach($namesArray as $id => $name) {
    $assocArray[$name] = (array_key_exists($id, $countArray)) ? $countArray[$id] : 0;
}
```

Comment: That assumes though that the two arrays have sequential numerical keys.

Comment: It assumes that the two arrays are of the same size. In my case, they are not. The count array is equal to or less than the id/name array.

Comment: (However, I didn't specify the size constraints in my original posting.)